# React: How do I get a HOC's state within the wrapped component? Can I get a simple example of how HOC's would pass such a value?

Tags: reactjs

I followed [this tutorial here](https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial) and took some of the logic for my own application. But because I have never made my own Higher Order Component before, nor worked with the Context API, I don't understand what's going on in the code.

For context, I have built two or three projects with React, but I never used the Context API or built a custom Higher Order Component with them. So I don't understand what I can do with those.

I am hoping to get the following out of this thread:

(1) Instructions on accessing my HOC's `this.state.authUser` value.
(2) An example of how a HOC can pass data from itself to the wrapped component.

Hypothetically they're basically the same question.

I think I've almost got access to the HOC's state in the wrapped component in my code, but I don't understand how to access the passed values in the wrapped component (its called "InboxPage"). Check out the HOC, `withAuthentication`:

```
import React from 'react';

import AuthUserContext from './context';
import { withFirebase } from '../Firebase';

const withAuthentication = Component => {
    class WithAuthentication extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                authUser: null,
            };
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            this.listener = this.props.firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(
                authUser => {
                    authUser
                        ? this.setState({ authUser })
                        : this.setState({ authUser: null });
                },
            );
        }

        componentWillUnmount() {
            this.listener();
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <AuthUserContext.Provider value={this.state.authUser}>
                    {/* <Component {...this.props} /> */}
                    <Component {...{ ...this.props, authUser: this.state.authUser }} />
                </AuthUserContext.Provider>
            );
        }
    }

    return withFirebase(WithAuthentication);
};

export default withAuthentication;
```

I think the `<AuthUserContext.Provider value={this.state.authUser}>` line should make `this.state.authUser` available within the the wrapped component if I `import AuthuserContext` again and place it in the render method like so:

```
class InboxPage extends Component {

// ...

render() {
        return (
             <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
                    <h1>Welcome to the Inbox.</h1>
                    <p>The Inbox is for authenticated users only.</p>
                </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
        )
    }
```

But that doesn't meet my needs because I have to have access to the value *outside* of the render method in the `componentDidMount` part of my InboxPage component.

I asked this question on Reddit and someone suggested changing `<Component {...this.props} />` to `<Component {...{ ...this.props, authUser: this.state.authUser }} />`. So I did. Then I tried writing in `InboxPage.js`:

```
componentDidMount() {

        console.log(this.props.authUser)
        this.props.firebase.getUsersChatrooms("placeholder").then(res => console.log("3:", res))
    }
```

but console.log logged a null value.

Edit: My ultimate goal is to use the `authUser` object set into withAuthentication state to get the username of the currently signed in user in my InboxPage component.

---

Oddly, this was a question I couldn't find on Google. My attempts to Google the question yielded *lots* of questions about "how do I pass the wrapped component's state up to the HOC?" but none about passing it back down. Examples: [Example one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44034814/how-to-access-a-wrapped-component-state-from-hoc), ["How to get state value into container?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45049629/reactjs-how-to-get-state-value-into-container) (was almost suitable), [this page](https://medium.com/@rossbulat/how-to-use-react-higher-order-components-c0be6821eb6c), and ["Can i pass component state to HoC?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54824123/can-i-pass-component-state-to-hoc). Again, I looked but my Google searches yielded results about passing state the opposite direction.

Help is greatly appreciated! I've been stuck for days because of my ineptitude. You guys are great!

Comment: You said you tried changing it to `<Component {...{ ...this.props, authUser: this.state.authUser }} />` but the `console.log` showed a `null` value. Isn't that exactly what you would expect? You're initializing `this.state.authUser` to `null` in the constructor, so of course that value will still be `null` in the child component's `componentDidMount()`. That should be the right approach here, because in a HOC you are simply rendering child component and can pass it whatever props (including state from the HOC) you want, there's nothing fancy about it.

Comment: The value I was expecting was the value of the ```authUser``` firebase object, which looks like a bunch of jibberish mixed in with useful info about the authenticated Firebase user. Maybe I got ```null``` because the code that changes ```this.state.authUser``` from ```null``` to ```authUser``` is async or something?